# Access denied while accessing a public samba share on windows 10

Tags: windows, linux-networking, samba

I'm trying to configure samba to share folders on my network publicly, however I also want private folders. I have ran into a problem where when I create the samba account access to all the shares are denied if your login as a samba user.
I'm connecting from a windows 10 PC
The file system is running Devuan 2.0.0 (a fork of Debian)

Here is what is contained in the samba.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP 
    dns proxy = no
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 100
    server role = standalone server
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = yes
    unix extensions = no
    
[Public]
    comment = pubic share
    hosts allow = 1.1.1.100/24, 127.0.0.1
    hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
    path = /mnt/Niflheim/Public
    public = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = no
    
[Private]    
    comment = home share
    hosts allow = 1.1.1.100/24, 127.0.0.1
    hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
    path = /mnt/Niflheim/Home
    valid users = USER, @USERGROUP
    read only = no
    browsable = no
    writeable = yes
    writeable list = USER
```

As an example if I create a samba account called USER and login as that then I can't access any shares but if I don't login all public shares are available.

Comment: which smb version are you using? Windows 10 has disabled smb1 by default.

Comment: I have already enabled smb1 on my windows device, as well as everyother type of smb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just turned out to be a problem with my computer and nothing wrong with the smb share.
Their is something wrong with how my computer is communicating with my dns server,

Just fixed it by reinstalling windows